# Trim dates from end of field if they exist in sql server

Tags: sql-server, date

I have an issue in SQL Server where I have a column that has a list of names that may or may not have a date of birth at the end. This column is then mail merged into a template that requires that only the name be displayed and not the date of birth.

The issue I am having is that, if all rows contain name and date of birth values, I could trim the dates of birth off the end. However, in cases where there is no date of birth on the end, how do I tell SQL to leave these rows alone and not trim the ends off?

eg:

```
COLUMN_NAME
John Doe 01/01/1990
Jane Smith 31/12/1991
Bob Fossil
```

My current code:

```
select ..., left (COLUMN_NAME, len(COLUMN_NAME) - 10) 
FROM...
```

This will take the dates of birth off John Doe and Jane Smith correctly, but I then end up with a blank for Bob Fossil (as it is 10 characters).

Comment: are the date of births always in the same format?

Comment: Yes always the same dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PATINDEX as a simple regular expression to check the date pattern, retrieve the starting index if present, and remove it.

Here the example

```
select 
case 
  when patindex('%[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' , COLUMN_NAME) > 0
  then substring(COLUMN_NAME, 0, patindex('%[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' , COLUMN_NAME))
  else COLUMN_NAME end, 
from Test;
```

See the fiddle for the thest: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1bb08/6/0

Comment: Either provide an answer, or write a comment.